# Wordpress plugin, jQuery load on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, wordpress

I am creating a site for Wordpress and I have installed a postcode search plugin. This plugin will be available when a user types in a postcode into a input then submits the form.

This postcode search uses javaScript and i'm wondering is there is any way that I can load the form on page load. I have tried to use the following but no luck

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(){return true;});
```

Is there anything else that needs to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply with :

```
$('#searchForm').submit();
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/